# html mail background has same color as text

Tags: mu4e

I'm using the material theme an mu4e. When opening some not all html mails, the background color of the mail becomes grey and the text becomes the same color, which leads to a blank "grey" page. Only selecting the text makes it visible.

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Place the cursor at the desired location where you wish to change the face, and type `C-u C-x =` to see what faces are present.  Without a theme, you can generally type `M-x customize-face` and adjust the desired face from there.  With a theme, however, it may be necessary to open it up and see what makes it tick with respect to the face you found at point.

Comment: this is what I get

Comment: Sorry that previous message was a typo. I managed to changed the text's color, but i still habe the light grey "overlay" thing. When I move my point there it changes the color to dark grey, which is the background color, which is ok for me. Non of the attributes that I can change seem to affect this overlay. `M-x customize-face` let's me customize what should be changed, like foreground at point and so on. But I cannot tell what this light grey overlay really is.

Comment: In general, `C-u C-x =` also gives information about overlays.  For example, if I highlight text in a scratch buffer and ensure that the cursor is at the beginning of the highlighted region, `C-u C-x =` tells me that there are overlays there that have the `region` face.  Sometimes, the `C-u C-x =` produces lots of results in the `*Help*` buffer and it takes a minute or two for the user to go through them all in order to better understand what is there.  I'd be very surprised if the face of the overlay you are interested in is not there in the `*Help*` buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem really was. I'm using a dark theme where html mails where rendered with `eww`. I found that setting `(setq shr-color-visible-luminance-min 80)` changed the way how mails were displayed and led to the text being displayed differently than the background.